# How to set "application rules" for svchost.exe file in comodo firewall to block everything except those I specify?

Tags: networking, security, firewall, whitelist, comodo-firewall

I am on a limited data plan when I travel and I use my computer connected on internet.

I would like to block everything, including windows update and other software updates.
I would like to allow only one web browser, firefox, chrome or opera.

How can I set up a config like this for `svchost.exe`?

I'm not an expert.

Comment: Unsure how to do it with comodo, but you can have windows 10 automatically block most updates just by setting the connection as metered. (This is part of the anniversary update.)

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/226722/how-when-and-why-to-set-a-connection-as-metered-on-windows-10/ - This should explain how to set it as metered.